# if all checkboxes checked in Jquery accordion change h3 bg

Tags: jquery, css, accordion

I have perused many of the other questions, nothing quite like this issue. I have a Jquery accordion, with 5 tabs. Inside each tab are several check boxes and I need the h3 at the top of the div to change color if ALL of the check boxes are checked. so when it is collapsed the user can easily identify which tabs still need attention.

The current Jquery I have tried is

```
function changeH3(){
$('h3').on('click',function(){
    var boxes = $('.checkbox[type="checkbox"]');
    if ( boxes.length === boxes.filter(':checked').length ) {
        $(this).closest('h3')
        .toggleClass('bg-warning')
        .toggleClass('bg-success'); 

    }
});
}
```

would be better if it just happened instead of needing the onclick as well.

the top panel looks like this, and the rest are pretty much the same. Its all Bootstrap CSS

```
 <div id= "acc1" >
   <form role="form" action="run.php" method="post" name='details'>

     <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">  
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="1"   onClick="checkval(this)" <?php echo $boxes[1] ? 'checked = "checked"' : '' ?>>Inspected 
     </fieldset>  

     <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">  
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="2" onClick="checkval(this)"<?php echo $boxes[2] ? 'checked = "checked"' : '' ?>>All 
     </fieldset> 

     <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">  
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="3" onClick="checkval(this)"<?php echo $boxes[3] ? 'checked = "checked"' : '' ?>>All 
     </fieldset>

     <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">  
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="4" onClick="checkval(this)"<?php echo $boxes[4] ? 'checked = "checked"' : '' ?>>aligns 
     </fieldset> 

     <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">  
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="5" onClick="checkval(this)"<?php echo $boxes[5] ? 'checked = "checked"' : '' ?>>and 
     </fieldset>

     <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">  
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="6" onClick="checkval(this)"<?php echo $boxes[6] ? 'checked = "checked"' : '' ?>> match 
     </fieldset> 

     <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">  
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="7" onClick="checkval(this)"<?php echo $boxes[7] ? 'checked = "checked"' : '' ?>>free 
     </fieldset> 

     <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">  
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="8" onClick="checkval(this)"<?php echo $boxes[8] ? 'checked = "checked"' : '' ?>>Front 
     </fieldset> 

     <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">  
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="9" onClick="checkval(this)"<?php echo $boxes[9] ? 'checked = "checked"' : '' ?>>Weather 
     </fieldset> 

     <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">  
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="10"  onClick="checkval(this)"<?php echo $boxes[10] ? 'checked = "checked"' : '' ?>>Key 
     </fieldset> 

     <textarea class= "form-control notes" name="notes[]" data-num="1" onChange="getVal(this)" placeholder = "If any of the above items were , etc."><?php echo $notes[1] ? $notes[1] : '' ?></textarea>

</div>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML & CSS to provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

I would consider triggering this action on a checkbox's click. On click, you could transverse up to the checkbox's parent container and select all checkboxes from there. Checking that selectors .length will give a # of how many total checkboxes there are in that panel. Then, select all checkboxes that are :checked. Comparing both .length results, you can determine if the h3 needs the class change.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function (event) {
  $target = $(this);
  $parent = $target.closest('.panel') // this selector may be incorrect
  $h3 = $target.find('h3');
  $checkboxes = $parent.find('input[type="checkbox"]');
  $checked = $parent.find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');

 if ($checked.length == $checkboxes.length) {
    $h3.addClass('bg-success'); 
    $h3.removeClass('bg-warning'); 
  } else {
   $h3.removeClass('bg-success'); 
   $h3.addClass('bg-warning');
  }
});
```

Comment: I have all of this saving to the database onClick. so if the user walks away they can re-open the page later and every checkbox is as it was with the appropriate backgrounds. I would like the same effect with bg-color of the h3. thats part of whats driving me nuts.

Comment: Could you do the same sort of check and render the h3 bg-color dynamically from the server?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following approach:

```js
// caching the <input> elements of 'type=checkbox':
var checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]');

// binding the anonymous function of the on() method as the
// change event-handler:
checkboxes.on('change', function() {

  // checking that the length of the checboxes collection is
  // equal to the length of checked checkboxes:
  let check = checkboxes.length === checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;

  // finding the closest ancestor <div> from amongs the ancestors of
  // the changed check-box element, and finding its direct child(ren)
  // <h3> elements (ideally a more specific selector should be used,
  // such as a class, id or data-* attribute):
  $(this).closest('div').find('>h3')
    // removing both the 'bg-warning' and 'bg-success'
    // classes from that <h3>
    .removeClass('bg-warning bg-success')
    // using a ternary conditional operator to
    // add the 'bg-success' class (if the check is true/truthy)
    // or the 'bg-warning' class (if the check is false/falsey):
    .addClass(check ? 'bg-success' : 'bg-warning');
  // triggering the change event - and thereby causing the change
  // event-handler to fire - on page-load/document-ready:
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="acc1">
  <h3>
  &lt;h3&gt; tag, for demo purposes (omitted from question's) HTML
</h3>
  <form role="form" action="run.php" method="post" name='details'>

    <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">
      <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="1" />Inspected
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">
      <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="2" />All
    </fieldset>

    <!-- note that, here, I removed an apparent duplicate 'All' check-box -->

    <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">
      <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="4" />aligns
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">
      <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="5" />and
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">
      <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="6" />match
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">
      <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="7" />free
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">
      <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="8" />Front
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">
      <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="9" />Weather
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">
      <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="10" />Key
    </fieldset>

    <textarea class="form-control notes" name="notes[]" data-num="1" onChange="getVal(this)" placeholder="If any of the above items were , etc."></textarea>
  </form>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3ae470of/).

This approach will assign the correct class (`bg-warning`/`bg-success`) on page-load/document-ready.

Incidentally, from a UI perspective it would be good practice to wrap the associated text of each `<input>` into a `<label>` tag either associating that `<label>` using its `for` attribute:

```
<input id="1" type="checkbox" />
<label for="1">Label for input 1</label>
```

or simply by wrapping the `<input>` in the same `<label>` as its text:

```
<label>
  <input id="1" type="checkbox/>Label for input 1
</label>
```

This allows the user to change the state of the check-box by clicking on its associated text (which increases the useful hit area for mouse or touch interaction):

```js
// caching the <input> elements of 'type=checkbox':
var checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]');

// binding the anonymous function of the on() method as the
// change event-handler:
checkboxes.on('change', function() {

  // checking that the length of the checboxes collection is
  // equal to the length of checked checkboxes:
  let check = checkboxes.length === checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;

  // finding the closest ancestor <div> from amongs the ancestors of
  // the changed check-box element, and finding its direct child(ren)
  // <h3> elements (ideally a more specific selector should be used,
  // such as a class, id or data-* attribute):
  $(this).closest('div').find('>h3')
    // removing both the 'bg-warning' and 'bg-success'
    // classes from that <h3>
    .removeClass('bg-warning bg-success')
    // using a ternary conditional operator to
    // add the 'bg-success' class (if the check is true/truthy)
    // or the 'bg-warning' class (if the check is false/falsey):
    .addClass(check ? 'bg-success' : 'bg-warning');
  // triggering the change event - and thereby causing the change
  // event-handler to fire - on page-load/document-ready:
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="acc1">
  <h3>
  &lt;h3&gt; tag, for demo purposes (omitted from question's) HTML
</h3>
  <form role="form" action="run.php" method="post" name='details'>

    <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="1" />Inspected</label>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="2" />All</label>
    </fieldset>

    <!-- note that, here, I removed an apparent duplicate 'All' check-box -->

    <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="4" />aligns</label>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="5" />and</label>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="6" />match</label>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="7" />free</label>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="8" />Front</label>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="9" />Weather</label>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="10" />Key</label>
    </fieldset>
    <textarea class="form-control notes" name="notes[]" data-num="1" placeholder="If any of the above items were , etc."></textarea>
  </form>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3ae470of/1/).

Further, the above can also be easily exported to plain JavaScript, albeit bootstrap.js does require jQuery to function, but if you're not using bootstrap.js, and for those looking to enable this functionality in future without using jQuery, the following may be a viable option:

```js
// declaring the function to act as the event-handler for the
// change-event; instantiating the opts variable as an Object
// in the event that no opts Object is passed to the function:
function conditionalToggleClass(opts = {}) {

  // defining the default settings for the function:
  let settings = {
    // the default element to style should none be passed-in:
    'targetElement': document.querySelector('body'),
    // the default class if the switch is true/truthy:
    'trueClass': 'success',
    // the default class if the switch is false/falsey:
    'falseClass': 'warning',
    // the default state of the 'switch':
    'switch': true
  };

  // obtaining an Array of keys from the opts Object, using
  // Object.keys(), and iterating over that array of keys using
  // Array.prototype.forEach().
  // Here we use the Arrow syntax to update the settings[key]
  // property value to that held in the opts[key] property-value:
  Object.keys(opts).forEach(key => settings[key] = opts[key]);

  // if we recieve a string in place of a node in the settings.targetElement
  // Object we use document.querySelector() to find the first, if any, matching
  // elements within the document; otherwise we use the node directly:
  let target = 'string' === typeof settings.targetElement ? document.querySelector(settings.targetElement) : settings.targetElement;

  // if the settings.switch is true/truthy we add the settings.trueClass
  // to the node, if it's false/falsey we remove that class:
  target.classList.toggle(settings.trueClass, settings.switch);

  // here we remove the settings.falseClass if the switch is true/truthy
  // by using the ! operator to  invert the switch's state, and add the
  // class if the switch is false:
  target.classList.toggle(settings.falseClass, !settings.switch);
}

// using document.querySelectorAll() to retrieve all <input> elements of
// that type and using Array.from() to convert that nodeList into an Array:
let checkboxes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')),

  // defining a new Event in order to fire that event to
  // set up the background-colour of the <h3> - or associated -
  // element on page-load:
  change = new Event('change');

// iterating over the Array of check-boxes using Array.prototype.forEach()
// to bind the event-handling function with EventTarget.addEventListener();
// to do this we use ES6 Arrow syntax:
checkboxes.forEach(check => check.addEventListener('change', function() {
  // here we call the function, and pass the opts Object:
  conditionalToggleClass({
    // we find the closest ancestor <div> element to the changed
    // node, and then within that node we find the first/only <h3> element
    // (as before the selector should be improved via class or id):
    'targetElement': this.closest('div').querySelector('h3'),

    // we set the class for when the switch is true:
    'trueClass': 'bg-success',
    // and for when the switch is false:
    'falseClass': 'bg-warning',

    // here we pass the switch state itself, by checking that the
    // number of checkboxes is equal to the number of checked check-boxes
    // (using Array.prototype.filter() to retain only the checked check-boxes):
    'switch': checkboxes.length === checkboxes.filter(check => check.checked).length
  });
}));

if (checkboxes.length) {
  checkboxes[0].dispatchEvent(change);
}
```

```css
.success {
  background-color: limegreen;
}
.warning {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="acc1">
  <h3>
  &lt;h3&gt; tag, for demo purposes (omitted from question's) HTML
</h3>
  <form role="form" action="run.php" method="post" name='details'>

    <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="1" />Inspected</label>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="2" />All</label>
    </fieldset>

    <!-- note that, here, I removed an apparent duplicate 'All' check-box -->

    <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="4" />aligns</label>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="5" />and</label>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="6" />match</label>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="7" />free</label>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="8" />Front</label>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="9" />Weather</label>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="form-horizontal form-group bg-info">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="box " name="checkBox[]" id="10" />Key</label>
    </fieldset>
    <textarea class="form-control notes" name="notes[]" data-num="1" placeholder="If any of the above items were , etc."></textarea>
  </form>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3ae470of/2/).

Please note that all of these approaches use ES6 features, such as: `let`, while others such as the last also use Arrow functions, `Array.from()`, and several experimental features such as `Element.closest()` to find the closest ancestor matching the given selector (this is, however, plain JavaScript and not a jQuery method despite the (almost) identical syntax and functionality).

References:

- CSS:

  - [CSS Attribute selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
  - [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`Array.createEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/createEvent).
  - [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
  - [Conditional (ternary) Operator: `assessment ? ifTrue : ifFalse;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
  - [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
  - [`EventTarget.dispatchEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent).
  - [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).
  - [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).
  - [`typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).
- jQuery:

  - [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
  - [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
  - [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
  - [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).

Comment: Thank you for your input about the UI stuff as well. I didn't do that because Label often ends up above the input itself. I was taken away from that project for a while to work on something new. I can return to the H3 question at a later point and i hope this answer works. it certainly does what I intend in the fiddle.